# Convert string to encoded hex

Tags: bash, hex

Not too sure about the operations going on here, but when I go to http://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter and enter `1yS9$dNc`, I see output: `3179533924644e63`.

In bash I do:

```
printf "1yS9$dNc" | xxd
0000000: 3179 5339                                1yS9
```

From the man page, I get that *xxd creates a hex dump of a given file or standard input*.

My question:

1. Can I use Bash to get the same output from codebeautify (i.e. go from `1yS9$dNc` to `3179533924644e63`).
2. How is codebeautify encoding this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *single* quotes. Compare:

```
$ printf "1yS9$dNc" | xxd
0000000: 3179 5339                                1yS9
```

With:

```
$ printf '1yS9$dNc' | xxd
0000000: 3179 5339 2464 4e63                      1yS9$dNc
```

The reason that your `xxd` output was short was that the shell expanded the value of `$dNc` to an empty string.  So, the only characters that `xxd` saw were `1yS9`.  If you use single-quotes, by contrast, the shell expands nothing.

Inside double quotes, the shell performs (1) variable expansion, (2) command substitution, (3) arithmetic expansion.  If you want those, use double-quotes,  If you don't use single-quotes.

#### Formatting options

To make the output look a little bit more like codebeautify, use `-g 0`:

```
$ printf '1yS9$dNc' | xxd -g 0
0000000: 3179533924644e63                  1yS9$dNc
```

Or, better yet, use `-plain`:

```
$ printf '1yS9$dNc' | xxd -plain
3179533924644e63
```

#### Saving the result in a variable

If the goal is to get the hex value into a shell variable, then, with bash:

```
$ printf -v var "%s" $(xxd -p <<<'1yS9$dNc')
$ echo $var
3179533924644e630a
```

Hat tip: David C. Rankin

Comment: I didn't explain myself very clearly, sorry about that. I am interested in 1) how to re-produced the output codebeautify gives using bash and 2) what is codebeautify doing differently. However, I appreciate you pointing out what I am doing wrong with `xxd`.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram: If you want a continuous string just use the `-p` option.

Comment: @John1024: I think `-p | -ps | -postscript | -plain` all do the same thing, so `-p` alone should work (*correct me if I'm wrong). It's odd how they use all of those apparently as one in the same.

Comment: @l'L'l Yes, it's very odd.  I chose `-plain` because the meaning was clear.  I would have expected `-postscript` or `-ps` to produce postscript output.

Comment: The only possible reason for having each I was thinking might be when used in combination with one of the other options perhaps, although from what I can tell that's not the case either... hmmm

Comment: You can also eliminate the pipe and preserve the value in a variable: `printf -v var "%s" $(xxd -p <<<'1yS9$dNc'); printf "hex: '%s'\n" $var`. This yields `hex: '3179533924644e630a'`

Comment: The here-string method `xxd -p <<< '1yS9$dNc'` _doesn't work_ as it adds a trailing newline. Also, the `printf -v` is a bit ridiculous since `var=$(printf '1yS9$dNc' | xxd -p)` will do the job just as good.

Comment: Where do you see a newline in the output above? Ridiculous? I beg to differ. If you are using bash, there is nothing ridiculous about it. You simply understand it is not portable to POSIX shells. It may be *less portable*, but it certainly isn't *ridiculous*.